# getting error while working with webdriver on an end to end testing

Tags: javascript, meteor, webdriver

I was trying to create an end to end testing using Chimp. In front end there are few inputs(type=text) and my task was to set few values on that input field. Using webdriver.io i tried to select the id of inputs set there values by using setValue. but could not succeed.

Here is the code :

```
var assert = require('chai').expect;
var should = require('chai').should();

var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');     


describe('Page title', function () {



    it('should @watch', function () {


        browser.url( 'http://localhost:3090/admin/createUser' );
        browser.setValue( '#usernameInput', 'Seeking Wisdom' );



    });
```

but nothing appeared in the input section. then i tried to do it with jquery :

```
 import $ from "jquery";

var assert = require('chai').expect;
var should = require('chai').should();

var webdriverio = require('webdriverio'); var options = {}; var browser=webdriverio.remote(options)

describe('Page title', function () {



    it('should @watch', function () {


        browser.url( 'http://localhost:3090/admin/createUser' );
        var selectBox = $('#usernameInput');
        browser.setValue( 'selectBox', 'Seeking Wisdom' );


        console.log(selectBox.getValue()); 
    });

});
```

but still its not working and getting this error.

```
Error: jQuery requires a window with a document
  at module.exports (node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:31:12)
  at Context.<anonymous> (tests/test.js:24:25)
  at /home/shahin/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/chimp/dist/lib/utils/fiberize.js:29:22
```

can anybody please tell me what really going on here?

Comment: ```tests/test.js```  is not in the client directory. Which means that any code within it will be run on both the client and the server. Which is why you're getting the Jquery error on the server. (there is no ```window``` or ```document``` object in the server)